# Query-based rules with auth.uid not working

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, database-design, firebase-security

I have the following structure:

```
events
-LEe7X118dkcH2JhJRe
    description: "Testdescr"
    eventTasks
    participants
        0zlwpSlCazNGjOyMi95h8awshrG2
            lastLogin: 1528641494535
            userKey: "0zlwpSlCazNGjOyMi95h8awshrG2"
            username: "User1"
        6LnYKxRu2SWUrxwIzId8dDpOrl02
            lastLogin: 152856590172
            userKey: "6LnYKxRu2SWUrxwIzId8dDpOrl02"
            username: "User2"
```

I want to query all events, to which an user participants (like a filter).
My Java-Code is:

```
mDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("event");
mDatabaseReference.orderByChild("participants/"+userId+"/userKey").equalTo(userId).addChildEventListener [...]
```

This works like a charm - i only receive the correct events.

Now i want to create query-based rules on server side (https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data).
So i created a read rule like:

```
".read": "query.orderByChild == 'participants/'+auth.uid+'/userKey' && query.equalTo == auth.uid"
```

**Problem**: i am not able to save that rule. Firebase gives me the error: "Invalid == expression: right operand must be an ordering or string literal when comparing against an ordering.". Why is it not possible to use "query.orderByChild" in combination with auth.uid?

What am i doing wrong?

**EDIT**:
Here are my complete rules:

```
{
  "rules": {         
    ".write": true,
     "event":{
       ".read": "query.orderByChild == 'participants/'+auth.uid+'/userKey' && query.equalTo == auth.uid"      
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you include your actual datastructure instead of a representation of it? Also can you add a bit more of your rules so everyone can understand were exactly they are placed within your structure.

Comment: @AndréKool i have edited the datastructure and added my complete rules.

Comment: I  think you can't have multiple values for query.orderByChild.  I have read  it somewhere in the documentation but I can't find the link again.

Comment: @Titou it should be possible. If i change the expression to "query.orderByChild == 'participants/SOMETHINGELSE/userKey' " it is working.

Just the expression: "query.orderByChild == auth.uid" is the problem.

Comment: @Jan You can have a path, the example given in the documentation is query.orderByChild == address/zipcode.  
But this path specification is the same for all users, so you data rules do not change when a new user logs in. What you are trying to do has a huge impact on the way data rules shoudl be processed. This is why I think using auth.uid  as a parameter of the query will fail.

Comment: Could you give me an alternative way to save a "participant" list and just allow the read on those events (on level higher), in which an user is part of?

Comment: @JanMöller I am having the same problem, did you solve it?

Comment: @rterrani i changed the database structure and introduced an additional "eventsForUser" table. That table contains every event key for each user. I create an ValueListener for every event.

Comment: Having the same problem. @JanMöller are you still using the "eventsForUser" table? Any issue with this method? Am I right that your table looks something like [this](https://pastebin.com/Bq6MREZj)?

Comment: @JanMöller Same problem here when doing query.orderByChild === auth.uid... Can you show us your alternative please ?