# Firebase rule alternative to query.orderByChild == auth.uid

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am trying to build a chat room where you can see all messages, except messages where you are excluded.
You (sadly) can't query "isNotEqualTo" with firebase that's why I had to cheat, here is a more clear example:

Let's imagine we have 3 users: user1, user2 and user3. user1 posted a message for all users except user2, this will be:

```
messages
   |__ 0
       |__ "author": "user1"
       |__ "message": "hello world"
       |__ "user1": true
       |__ "user3": true
```

Now I can query:

```
firebase.database().ref("messages").orderByChild(myAuthUid).equalTo(true)...
```

→ user1 and user3 will see the message.

→ user2 will not.

Now I try to build the appropriate rule forcing only this query, which should looks like `query.orderByChild == auth.uid && equalTo == true`

The problem here is `query.orderByChild == auth.uid` which refers this error:

> "Invalid == expression: right operand must be an ordering or string
>   literal when comparing against an ordering."

A ticket has been submited to firebase support but idk how much time it would take so solve this problem that's why I'm looking for an alternative.

Another topic in link with this problem: [Query-based rules with auth.uid not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50787713/query-based-rules-with-auth-uid-not-working#comment92950615_50787713)

I love so much firebase but something that I thought easy is becoming a big deal for me, any idea guys ?

Comment: This seems like a bug, because you get the same error even if you do: `query.orderByChild == 'auth.uid'`, which should use the exact string representation of `"auth.uid"` as a string literal (not a variable). It might be worth pinging [@FrankvanPuffelen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/209103/frank-van-puffelen) a message to see if he can shed any light on this.

Comment: @Grimthorr query.orderByChild == 'auth.uid' is I think another problem. I already tried that and I think the dot "." represents something that's why you can't use it like that. Try for example to replace 'auth.uid' by 'hello.world' you'll get an error too...

Comment: ...As I said a ticket has been submited so not sure there is a solution yet. Extract from my discussion with @Ritz from Firebase support: "But for some reason, auth.uid is not treated as a string." "For now, I would suggest to avoid using query.orderByChild == auth.uid on your rules in order to continue on with your work."

Comment: That's correct, likely because `.` is not a valid character for a node name, but it is still technically a string literal in this form, so the error doesn't quite match up. I guess you might get away with using just `query.equalTo == auth.uid` instead, if you adjusted your structure to use the user ID as both the key and value (for example: `"user1": "user1"`).

Comment: What do you mean ?

Comment: I'll post an answer with a little more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a bug, especially as the rule system seems to be doing some additional sanity checks that the error message doesn't relay. For example, using `query.orderByChild == 'auth.uid'` doesn't work either, even though this is technically a (invalid) string literal.

As a workaround, you might get away with using just `query.equalTo == auth.uid` as a security rule, but this will mean adjusting your database structure to follow the below format instead:

```
messages
   |__ 0
       |__ "author": "user1"
       |__ "message": "hello world"
       |__ "user1": "user1"
       |__ "user3": "user3"
```

So instead of using `true` for the value of each user, you'd use the user's ID (to match the key name). Therefore your query would need to look something like:

```
firebase.database().ref("messages").orderByChild(myAuthUid).equalTo(myAuthUid)
```

And your security rule would be:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth.uid != null && query.equalTo == auth.uid"
  }
}
```

As you've raised this with Firebase support, they might be able to provide a little more insight or issue a fix, but this should work for the time being.

Comment: This can be a good provisional solution, I don't know why I didn't think of that earlier (the fun fact is I first used userid as value like that). Thank you !